# I just decided to try Ububtu and want to know how to get it on the computer from the disc i made?

Tags: software-installation

deided to try and ditch windows xp and found ubuntu and put it on disc last night , I need to know how to have it boot on my computer from the disc

Answer (score 1):

First, it is very important that you made a disc with an image of the ISO-file, and not only a copy oft the ISO-file. Note that only an image is bootable. With a copy your comp can't boot from the disc! Nearly every burning program has the option to burn an image instead of make a copy, but you have to choose this option befor burning. I'm not sure if your expression "put it on disc" really mean "burning an image".

Second, you have to change the BIOS options of your comp: It has to boot first from the CD or DVD drive. Often the setting is to boot first from the harddisk. You find the boot options in the BIOS settings of your comp. You have to entry the BIOS during the booting (often with the DEL key, but it's normally shown below on the boot screen what key to press). Then you have to go to the boot options (normally all options are on the top of the BIOS setting as a bar). Then you have to change the boot order (often by the arrow keys, but it's shown normally on the right of the screen). Please note you have to save the new configuration of the BIOS after the change (often by F10-key, but this is shown too on the right).

After that, you comp will boot from a disc if there is a bootable image on it.

You can test ubuntu first as a live system, without any change of your comp. If you are sure to install Ubuntu, you can beginn the installing.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will have to create a bootable CD/DVD. you can use nero or any other software you like(you can also create a bootable pen-drive using YUMI from pendrivelinux.com)

then insert the storage device in your system and restart it.

Now on a screen you will see something written like : Press ..... for .....

from those, press the button for boot order and then from there choose CD/DVD or USB device (whichever you have created).

Now you will get option of firstly trying Ubuntu an then install or directly install.
choose as per your convinience. If you choose ' Try Ubuntu', then on desktop there will be an icon stating "Install it", which will install ubuntu on your device.